# No service for type 'IServiceProviderFactory[Autofac.ContainerBuilder]' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, autofac

When running the following command to add database migration script, I get the following error:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -v -o .\Migrations\ --context MyContext
```

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProviderFactory`1[Autofac.ContainerBuilder]' has been registered.

I have followed [this](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting) documentation. The `Startup` class is implemented as it follows:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        WebHostingEnvironment = env;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        this.Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.AddCustomDbContext(Configuration);
        services.AddOptions();
    }

    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    { }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
        ConfigureEventBus(app);
    }
}
```

Any thought on what causes the error, and how I can fix it?

The versions:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.9.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
```

Comment: Can you share `AddCustomDbContext`?

Comment: Sure, please see the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ConfigureServices` with the following:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    services.AddCustomDbContext(Configuration);
    services.AddOptions();

    var container = new ContainerBuilder();
    container.Populate(services);
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container.Build());
}
```

**Note that this totally contradicts what [Autofac's docs suggest](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting)**, but it was required to resolve the issue.

> Add services to the collection. Don't build or return any IServiceProvider or the ConfigureContainer method won't get called.

Comment: This means you are using an older version of .net core. Latest version of .net-core does not allow `ConfigureServices` to return `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: interesting, please check `CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0` the versions I added in the question. Not sure if they're not current latest major versions.

Answer (score 6):

You have to configure Autofac in Program.cs:

```
var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(cb =>
            {
                cb.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false).AddEnvironmentVariables();
            }).UseStartup<Startup>();
```

or

```
 return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {   
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```